# Regex to Upper Case all words but exclude ' (apostrophe)

Tags: javascript, regex, function, uppercase, apostrophe

I'm trying to build a funct to UpperCase all the string words but I'm having a problem with the following:

```
String.prototype.upper = function() {
    return this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)/g, chr => chr.toUpperCase())
 }


let str = "My uncle's car is red";
console.log(str.upper()) 


//My Uncle'S Car Is Red
```

I need to exclude the **S** from being UpperCased, after the apostrophe.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Just add `'` in character class to make it `/[^a-zA-Z0-9']+(.)/g`

Comment: I doubt adding `'` is the only thing to do. You should only avoid matching `'s` when there is no word char after `s` and there is a letter before `'`

Comment: What should be the result for: `o'connor's car is red`?

Comment: Try `/(?<![-\p{L}0-9])\p{Ll}(?<!\p{L}'s(?![\p{L}0-9]))/gu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the Regex to `\s+\w` to search for a letter after spaces and/or tabs.

```js
const upper = (input) => input.replace(/\s+\w/g, x => x.toUpperCase());
console.log(upper("My uncle's car is red"));
```

Comment: It worked on the editor, but is clashing on Codewars. Don't know why. Asked for help. Lets see.